# Is there a way to get more home Xbox switches?

Tags: xbox-one

Every summer I go on vacation and while I'm at my vacation house I set the Xbox there to my home Xbox because my internet is bad. But now it's saying I only have 4 switches left so is there a way to get more home Xbox switches or am I stuck with 10?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I can tell, there is no way to increase the limit of switches for setting an Xbox One as your home console.

However, you are allowed to switch your home Xbox One up to 5 times per year starting the date of your first switch. As long as you don’t switch your home consoles frequently (e.g. one switch to your vacation location and one switch back to your home location) you should be fine.

[Source](https://support.xbox.com/en-US/games/game-setup/my-home-xbox)

Answer (score -3):

You can take a survey now to get a 6th one

Comment: Do you have a source for this? What survey are you talking about?